# Use array_search but continue searching after result found (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been playing around with array_search. I have been trying to search an array and get details from it. The problem is, once it finds the result it moves on, it doesn't check for duplicates in the array. I can't seem to work out my loop logic, any suggestions?

The `$names` array

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Fred
            [age] => 20
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => George
            [age] => 17
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sarah
            [age] => 22
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Fred
            [age] => 30
        )
)
$name=" Fred";
//loop here
$array_position = array_search($name, array_column($names, 'name'));
$array_data = $names[$array_position];

echo $array_data['name'] . " is: " . $array_data['age'] . " years old.
//end loop
```

**Result:**

Fred is 20 years old.

**Expected result:**

Fred is 20 years old

Fred is 30 years old.

I tried `array_keys()` but I don't understand php.net very well

Should I try store the results in a separate array and then loop that to print? Seems like there should be a more efficient/elegant solution.

Comment: Use in_array() instead of array_search()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Ben first of all array_search() return true or false not the key, but for your desired output you can simply try with foreach() with a condition like below or with array_key:

with foreach()

```
<?php
    $names = array(0 => 
                array(              
                        "name" => "Fred",
                        "age" => 20
                    ),
                1 => array(
                        "name" => "George",
                        "age" => 17
                    ),
                2 => array(
                        "name" => "Sarah",
                        "age" => 22
                    ),
                3 => array(
                        "name" => "Fred",
                        "age" => 30
                    )
            );

    $name= "Fred";
    echo "<pre>";
    foreach($names as $val){
        if($val["name"] == $name){
            echo $name . " is: " . $val["age"] . " years old.\n";
        }
    }
```

with array_key()

```
<?php
    $names = array(0 => 
                array(              
                        "name" => "Fred",
                        "age" => 20
                    ),
                1 => array(
                        "name" => "George",
                        "age" => 17
                    ),
                2 => array(
                        "name" => "Sarah",
                        "age" => 22
                    ),
                3 => array(
                        "name" => "Fred",
                        "age" => 30
                    )
            );
    $name=" Fred";
    $array_position = array_keys(array_column($names, "name"), "Fred");
    foreach($array_position as $key){
        echo $names[$key]["name"] . " is: " . $names[$key]["age"] . " years old.\n";
    }
```

OUTPUT:

Fred is: 20 years old.

Fred is: 30 years old.

Answer (score 2):

use array_filter to find all.

```
function search($array, $key)
{
  return array_filter($array, function($v) use($key){return $v['name'] == $key;});
}

$result = search($array, $key);
foreach($result as $v)
{
  echo $v['name'] . " is: " . $v['age'] . " years old.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with a simple foreach loop?

```
// Declare the array
$names = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Fred',
        'age' => 20
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'George',
        'age' => 17
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Sarah',
        'age' => 22
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Fred',
        'age' => 30
    )
);

// Name to search
$name = 'Fred';

foreach($names as $index => $data){
    if($data['name'] == $name)
        echo $data['name'] . ' is ' . $data['age'] . ' years old.<br>';
}
```

And the result would be:

```
Fred is 20 years old.
Fred is 30 years old.
```

Answer (score 1):

[array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) can do this:

```
<?php
$names = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Fred',
        'age' => 20
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'George',
        'age' => 17
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Sarah',
        'age' => 22
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Fred',
        'age' => 30
    )
);

$matchKeys = array_keys( array_column($names, 'name'), 'Fred' );
array_map(function($arrKey) use ($names) {
    echo $names[$arrKey]['name'] . " is: " . $names[$arrKey]['age'] . " years old.\n";
}, $matchKeys);
```

Result:

```
Fred is: 20 years old.
Fred is: 30 years old.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Fred,
            [age] => 20
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => George,
            [age] => 17
        ),
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sarah,
            [age] => 22
        ),
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Fred,
            [age] => 30
        )
)

$name="Fred";

//loop here
for($i =0; i<count($names); $i++){
    if($arr[$i] == $name)echo $name . ' is ' . $names[$i] ."years old.<br>";
}
//end loop
```

Output:

```
Fred is 20 years old

Fred is 30 years old
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help -

```
$check_name= 'Fred'; // set the name to check
$temp= array_filter($names, function($a) use($check_name) {
    return $a['name'] === $check_name; // return if matches
});
// loop through the result
foreach($temp as $v) {
   echo $v['name'] . ' is ' . $v['age'] . ' years old.<br>'; 
}
```

**Output**

```
Fred is 20 years old.
Fred is 30 years old.
```

[Working code](https://eval.in/737194)

[Anonymous function & use keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you gave space in $name variable 
   $name = " Fred";

Here is your code,

```
$name=" Fred";
function array_search_custom($needle,$haystack) {
    $temp = [];
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        if(trim($needle)===trim($value)) {
            $temp[] =$key;

        }
    }
    return $temp;
}
$name=" Fred";
$a_names = array_column($names, 'name');
$a_ages = array_column($names, 'age');
$array_position = array_search_custom($name, $a_names);
foreach($a_names as $k => $v){
  if($array_position && in_array($k, $array_position)){    
    echo $a_names[$k] . " is: " . $a_ages[$k] . " years old.<br/>";
  }
}
```

I trimmed your name and wrote custom array search function as per your requirement.

Give it a try, it will work.